# How can I code a client-server Java program that uses the client computer's monitors as second or third monitors for the server one?

Tags: java, android, client-server, desktop, monitor

In short I am interested in a Java code that allows a computer to:

1) think it has a second monitor (virtual monitor without having a device atached)

2) regulairly extract pixel information from that virtual second monitor created (create a BufferedImage/*.bmp file with the current image of that virtual monitor at a given time by pressing a button for example)

3) would be interesting to see a second monitor in a JPanel placed inside a JFrame and update continuously (for testing).

4) hopefully be able to easily transfer pixel information with multiple threads to a mobile device (android) through EDGE/3G/WI-FI (or other means)

I believe this has to be possible. There have been applications such as iDisplay(android second monitor through USB or WI-FI. Forces creation of a second monitor in windows settings) and AirDisplay (displays second monitor on android as long as PC and device are on the same WI-FI network), but are very unstable, unreliable and mess up desktop settings, there have been system crashes and lockups and they don't work for my system.

I am interested in any ideas on the matter, because it seems like it will come down to messing with the Windows/other OS structure to make it work... and doing that in Java seems even harder.

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My final goal is to find a way to use an android tablet/phone as a second monitor for a Windows 7/XP PC. It all comes down to the idea of emulating a second monitor through code... at least that is how I see it and I am trying to write a simple code for loading image information of that monitor into memory.

Comment: You need a driver for Windows first.  Your best bet is to look for a driver which can talk to a VNC Server.  I have no idea if such beasts easiest - I would suggest asking at superusers.  Then you need a vnc server for your phone